# Singapore airlines changed my flight by +5h, can I get a refund?

Tags: air-travel, tickets, cancellations, refunds, singapore-airlines

I bought a ticket in a promotion, according to Singapore airlines, so that ticket is non-refundable. However, the airline sent me an email that my flight got reschedule by over 5h earlier. I sent them an email saying tha

Comment: have you checked your terms and conditions of flying on the ticket you bought?

Comment: The ticket has "non-refundable" on it and I tried to look for details on their refund policy, but all it says is that that non-refundable tickets are not-refundable, but it does not say anything about what happens when the airline changes my flight. This seems crazy to me that they change the flight and force me to take it.
Here is their refund policy page: https://www.singaporeair.com/en_UK/us/travel-info/charges-changes/cancellations-refunds/

Comment: Half your question seems to be missing?

Comment: Your title says +5h, your body says -5h.

Comment: What was their response to your email saying tha

Answer (score 3):

Article 10 Flight Schedules, Cancellations etc. of Singapore Airline’s T&Cs states that (a) If Carrier cancels, terminates, diverts or fails to operate a flight reasonably according to schedule, is unable to provide previously confirmed space, fails to stop at a Passenger’s stopover or destination point, or causes the Passenger to miss a connecting flight on which he holds a reservation, the options are:

(1) carry the Passenger as soon as it can on its scheduled service; or

(2) re-route the Passenger to the destination indicated on the Ticket or applicable portion thereof (no fee) or

(3) make a refund in accordance with the provisions of Article 11 Paragraph 3.

In general, they have to agree the preferred option with you.

Source: https://www.singaporeair.com/en_UK/global_footer/conditions-carriage/

Comment: So a 5 hour change is not 'reasonably according to schedule'? What would be the limit of 'reasonably'?

Comment: @simon at rcl I couldn’t find a specific definition of that in the airline’s T&Cs. This https://www.godsavethepoints.com/things-you-can-do-when-an-airline-changes-flights-schedule/ states a significant change is generally defined as any departure or arrival change over an hour, a date change, a routing change or an aircraft change. The limit appears to vary by carrier, as in the examples quoted here https://www.moneysavingexpert.com/travel/flight-changes/ IMHO most people would view a 5+ hour change as significant, whether they’d accept it would depend on the circumstances.